# map - key to select the current line

Tags: vim

While doing my first mapping in vim, I'm having trouble to understand why my mapping isn't working as expected:

```
:map - <S-Left>v
```

When clicking on `-` in normal mode, I expect that the current line will be selected and I will be in insert mode.

But it doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
:map - <S-Left-v>
:map - <S-Left v>
```

Also, is there a place where I can learn the syntax? I feel like I'm guessing too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> is simply <kbd>V</kbd>. The command is just [`V`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#V):

```
:nnoremap - V
```

Well, you can use `<S-V>` for <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> but what for?

Comment: can you explain what was bad in my solution? is it the syntax?

Comment: `<S-Left>` means `Shift` + `Left`. Do you really mean it? `Shift` + `left arrow` + letter `v`? Or you tried `Left shift`?

Comment: no. thanks. what is your answer different than `:map - V` ?

Comment: [`:nn[oremap]`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:nnoremap): Only for Normal mode, no recursion (used to redefine a command).